# Android: how to automatically refresh an element on the UI (without refreshing the entire screen)

Tags: android

I want to refresh my tile after clicking on a Download all button. I m using GridAdapter to display a grids for multiple videos. So If i click on Download all Button tile grid should show a progress bar, But currently it is not showing without refreshing the entire page.

We have tried below mentioned code on button click event but application getting crashed.....

```
handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do something after 100ms
        File tempfile = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(course_name),productCode);
        if(tempfile.exists()){
            viewHolder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iewHolder.mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            File tempthumbfile = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(course_name),fname);
            Log.d("tempthumbfile-->",""+tempthumbfile);
            if(tempthumbfile.exists()){
                viewHolder.mImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(course_name),fname).getAbsolutePath()));
            }
            viewHolder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            viewHolder.mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
    }
}, 1500);
```

Comment: YOu have to show what have you tried so we can help

Comment: Give inputs regarding how you are updating your title after Download button click.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific, but try the following two approaches:

1) First and foremost, if you want to refresh a specific tile in your grid. Just call `TileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

2) If you are trying to e.g. blur the entire Grid and show a loading bar on top of it. Find a reference to the View hosting the grid and call `view.invalidate();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.We already tried this but its not worked. Please give me example in detail.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        this.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // TODO: add your job/functionality here
            }
        });
    }
}
```